# Using PHP DOMDocument to search for one class among many

Tags: php, domdocument

I have some elements in my DOM with multiple classes one of which is `.dictionary_entry`. I need to look for any instance of this class in my DOM and I am using the following PHP code for that:

```
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
$check = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $divs->length; $i++) {
    $node = $divs->item($i);
    if ($node->getAttribute('class') == 'cross-entry') { $check = 1; }
}
```

However, this doesn't work since the `div` in question has other classes as well, e.g., `<div class="cross-entry cross-one one-more-class">`

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check for whitespace in the string.
2. If it exists, explode the classes on `whitespace`.
3. Check if the class you want is in the array
4. Otherwise, check if the single class that exists matches
5. Otherwise, set `$check` to 0.

That would look like this:

```
$class = $node->getAttribute('class');
$is_whitespace = preg_match('/\s/', $class);
if($is_whitespace){
    $classes = explode(' ', $class);
    if(in_array('cross-entry', $classes)){
        $check = 1;
    }
} elseif($class == 'cross-entry'){
    $check = 1;
} else {
    $check = 0;
}
```